Gradle Task Execution Failed: Could Not Resolve Dependencies in Android Project
I encountered an error while trying to build my Android project using Gradle. The build fails with the following error message:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkHqDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:hqDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find br.com.zbra:android-linq:1.0.1.
     ...
   > Could not find com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1.
     ...
   > Could not find id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4.
     ...

Details:
Android Studio Version: 2024.1.1.13
Gradle Version: 7.3.3
Project Configuration:
*The dependencies are listed in the build.gradle file of the app module as follows:
implementation 'br.com.zbra:android-linq:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4'

What I’ve Tried:

Double-checked the dependency coordinates.
Cleared the Gradle cache and re-synced the project.
Verified that the repositories are correctly listed in the build.gradle file.
Tried downloading the dependencies manually and placing them in the libs folder.

Repositories: I have tried searching for these dependencies in various repositories, including Maven Central, JitPack, Google Maven, and local libs folder, but the build process still fails to find them.
I’m looking for advice on how to resolve this issue. Are these dependencies hosted in a specific repository that I’m missing, or is there an alternative way to include them in my project? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Going over the repositories you have shared, you can see that:

For br.com.zbra:android-linq:1.0.1, this repository was hosted on Maven, but it was 6 years ago. The website linking to it does not exist (https://zbra-solutions.github.io/android-linq/)

For com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1, this library is even older (from 2017) and it seems to not exist anymore (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.patrickpissurno/ripple-effect/1.3.1)

For https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/id.zelory/compressor/1.0.4, this library is from 2018, but it does seem to have newer versions so I would try working with that (https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor)


As for the first two, I would search for different libraries that allow for the same use case.
